# Is it possible to implement a FlowLayout with RelativeLayout properties?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a custom RelativeLayout that has two views in one row: one on the left side of the screen (android:layout_alignParentStart="true") and one on the right (android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"). The view on the right will grow toward the left view until it takes up all the space between the two views. Then it will move to a new line under the view on the left.

I have implemented a slightly modified version of Romain Guy's FlowLayout that extends RelativeLayout. However, this class seems to ignore the RelativeLayout's align properties and just sticks the views right next to each other. Is there a way to implement a such a layout that will anchor the views to the left and right?

FlowLayout class:

```
public class FlowLayout extends RelativeLayout {

private int mHorizontalSpacing;
private int mVerticalSpacing;

public FlowLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlowLayout);
    mHorizontalSpacing = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable
            .FlowLayout_horizontalSpacing, 0);
    mVerticalSpacing = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable
            .FlowLayout_verticalSpacing, 0);
    attributes.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int width = 0;
    int height = getPaddingTop();

    int currentWidth = getPaddingStart();
    int currentHeight = 0;

    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (currentWidth + child.getMeasuredWidth() > widthSize) {
            height += currentHeight + mVerticalSpacing;
            currentHeight = 0;
            width = Math.max(width, currentWidth);
            currentWidth = getPaddingEnd();
        }

        int spacing = mHorizontalSpacing;
        if (lp.spacing > -1) {
            spacing = lp.spacing;
        }

        lp.x = currentWidth + spacing;
        lp.y = currentHeight;

        currentWidth += child.getMeasuredWidth();
        currentHeight = Math.max(currentHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());
    }

    width += getPaddingEnd();
    height += getPaddingBottom();

    setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(width, widthMeasureSpec), resolveSize(height,
            heightMeasureSpec));

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        child.layout(lp.x, lp.y, lp.x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), lp.y + child
                .getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return p instanceof LayoutParams;
}

@Override
protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout
            .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

@Override
protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return new LayoutParams(p.width, p.height);
}

@Override
public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
}

public static class LayoutParams extends RelativeLayout.LayoutParams {

    public int spacing;

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable
                .FlowLayout_LayoutParams);
        spacing = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable
                .FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layoutSpacing, -1);
        attributes.recycle();
    }

    public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that rather than calculating the right view's new position yourself, you can change its LayoutParams and have the OS handle positioning for you. I created a custom layout that extends RelativeLayout and overrides the onMeasure() method. This will adjust the LayoutParams accordingly.

More specifically:
Call the super method then find the widths of the two views and their parent in `onMeasure()`. Use these to figure out if the right view will overlap the left view. If so, change the right view's `layout_alignParentEnd="true"` property to be `layout_alignParentStart="true"` and give it the `layout_below="@id/left_view"` property. Do the opposite when there will be no overlap. Call the super method again to have the OS remeasure the views for you.

The layout class:

```
public class WrappingLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView leftView;
    private EditText rightView;
    //Use this to prevent unnecessarily adjusting the LayoutParams
    //when the right view is already in the correct position
    private boolean isMultiline = false;

    public WrappingLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrapping_layout, this);

        leftView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_view);
        rightView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.right_view);
    }

    public WrappingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrapping_layout, this);

        leftView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_view);
        rightView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.right_view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //Call first to make sure the views' initial widths have been set
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int screenWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int leftViewWidth = getPaddingStart() + leftView.getMeasuredWidth() + leftView.getPaddingEnd();
        int rightViewWidth = getPaddingEnd() + rightView.getMeasuredWidth() + rightView.getPaddingStart();

        LayoutParams rightViewParams = (LayoutParams) rightView.getLayoutParams();
        if (!isMultiline && rightViewWidth + leftViewWidth > screenWidth) {
            isMultiline = true;
            rightViewParams.addRule(BELOW, R.id.left_view);
            rightViewParams.removeRule(ALIGN_PARENT_END);
            rightViewParams.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            //Call again here to adjust dimensions for new params
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else if (isMultiline && rightViewWidth + leftViewWidth < screenWidth) {
            isMultiline = false;
            rightViewParams.removeRule(BELOW);
            rightViewParams.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_END);
            rightViewParams.removeRule(ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            //Call again here to adjust dimensions for new params
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

The layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/left_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/right_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>

</merge>
```